# Prediction in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
```

The above 4 lines of code are from a model I came across. Can somebody tell me the difference between y_test and y_pred.

Comment: `y_test` is just `y_true` while `y_pred` is the prediction of your model,  the result of `clf.predict(X_test)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y_test` is the actual label set which is used to evaluate your final model performance in comparison with `y_pred`, which is the one we get after fitting our machine learning model, i.e. what our model would predict for `X_test`.